# Is Igneel really dead?

Tags: fairy-tail

In *Fairy Tail*, Igneel has been missing for 7 years, so I'm guessing he's dead but I don't know!

Is Igneel dead?

Answer (score 2):

These are heavy spoilers, so read at your own discretion:

> Igneel and the other dragons took part in the [400-year plan](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/The_400_Year_Plan) in order to save themselves from the deterioration of their souls caused by Acnologia. Through theis plan, the dragons were sealed inside their children, and then they were sent 400 years into the future into a world that was teeming with Ethernano which allowed their souls to heal while inside their children. Natsu and the other dragon slayers were never aware that they had been sent into the future nor that the dragons had been sealed inside them.

Comment: that is one part of the story and there is another part. I don't know it has been shown in anime or not but your answer is incomplete

Comment: Yes, this is shown in anime.

Answer (score 2):

[Igneel](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Igneel) is dead. If you read the status, then you will see "deceased" written.

> Natsu thought that Igneel was dead, but actually, he was inside Natsu.

In Tartaros Arc,

> Igneel comes out from Natsu's body and fights with Acnologia and then supposedly dies. But if he was dead, he could not talk to Natsu, and this did not happen. Also, Igneel said the dragons were inside the body of the dragon slayer, summing up that Igneel is dormant inside Natsu's body again.

Answer (score 0):

I think Igneel didn't die.

When I read the manga almost at the point when The End power tries to devour natsu, it was Igneel who help Natsu to make it out alive. Though, it might be the projection of Igneel.

Comment: You should add some more descriptions like chapter of manga or the pic of manga where the incident took place